# Mimic radiobuttons in datagridview using DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

PLEASE NOTE: this question is about `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`s inside a `DataGridView` control - *not* the normal `CheckBox` control.

I have a winforms app that contains a `DataGridView` with three checkbox (`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`) columns. I'd like to mimic radiobuttons ie. one, and only one, checkbox is checked at a time. I am able to turn off the other checkboxes in the grid when one is clicked as follows:

```
Private Sub dgvNormalReports_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvNormalReports.CellClick
  If mblnSuppressUI Then Exit Sub
  mblnSuppressUI = True
  If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 And e.ColumnIndex <= dgvNormalReports.ColumnCount - 1 And e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.RowIndex <= dgvNormalReports.Rows.Count - 1 Then
    Select Case dgvNormalReports.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
      Case "dclLeaveOnThisList", "dclPrintLetter", "dclNoLetterNeeded" 'mimic radiobutton - turn off other checkboxes
        dgvNormalReports.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dclLeaveOnThisList").Value = False
        dgvNormalReports.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dclPrintLetter").Value = False
        dgvNormalReports.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dclNoLetterNeeded").Value = False
        'N.B. current cell's checked status is changed AFTER this event
      Case Else
        'ignore
    End Select
  End If
  mblnSuppressUI = False
End Sub
```

The problem I am having is that if the user clicks on a checkbox that is already checked, it becomes unchecked, and then none of the three checkboxes are checked. I always want one (and only one) checkbox ticked at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, **edit your three DataGridView columns and set each columns property ReadOnly to true** (this will prevent user from changing the values)

1. dclLeaveOnThisList
2. dclPrintLetter
3. dclNoLetterNeeded

and second, use the following code below

```
Private Sub dgvNormalReports_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvNormalReports.CellClick
  If mblnSuppressUI Then Exit Sub
  mblnSuppressUI = True
  If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 And e.ColumnIndex <= dgvNormalReports.ColumnCount - 1 And e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.RowIndex <= dgvNormalReports.Rows.Count - 1 Then

    Dim tmpColName As String = dgvNormalReports.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
    With dgvNormalReports.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Select Case tmpColName 
        Case "dclLeaveOnThisList", "dclPrintLetter", "dclNoLetterNeeded" 'mimic radiobutton - turn off other checkboxes
                'Unchecked all checkboxes besides the selected one
                If tmpColName <> "dclLeaveOnThisList" Then .Cells("dclLeaveOnThisList").Value = False
                If tmpColName <> "dclPrintLetter" Then .Cells("dclPrintLetter").Value = False
                If tmpColName <> "dclNoLetterNeeded" Then .Cells("dclNoLetterNeeded").Value = False

             'Ensures that the selected cell is checked
             .Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True

        End Select

    End With

  End If
  mblnSuppressUI = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it does what I need and is the simplest. Thanks to everyone that answered!

Comment: `dgvNormalReports.InvalidateRow(e.RowIndex)` is also useful if you want to update the formatting

Answer (score 2):

Use `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event handler.

```
Private Sub dgvNormalReports_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvNormalReports.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If Me.dgvNormalReports.IsCurrentCellDirty = True Then
        If Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.GetType() = GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) Then
            If Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentCell.Value = False Then
                'Update only if changed from false to true
                If Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.Equals("dclLeaveOnThisList") = false Then Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentRow.Cells("dclLeaveOnThisList").Value = False
                If Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.Equals("dclPrintLetter") = false Then Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentRow.Cells("dclPrintLetter").Value = False
                If Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.Equals("dclNoLetterNeeded") = false Then Me.dgvNormalReports.CurrentRow.Cells("dclNoLetterNeeded").Value = False

                Me.dgvNormalReports.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
            Else
                'Prevent changes
                Me.dgvNormalReports.CancelEdit()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have predefined columns in `datagridview`, then may be better will be used a generated by VisualStudio column objects:

```
Me.dclLeaveOnThisList.Name
Me.dclPrintLetter.Name
Me.dclNoLetterNeeded.Name
```

Comment: good idea using CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged like you did! complimenti! ps: I edited your answer because you use dgvTest1 in a line of code.

Comment: My editing is still not visible but I notice now that rowindx is useless.

Comment: Updated answer, and didn't find `dgvTest1` anymore from there

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of these DataGridView events:

- *CellValueChanged*
- *CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged*
- *CellBeginEdit*

You can use *CellValueChanged* instead of *CellClick* because CellClick event occurs when any part of a cell is clicked, including borders and padding ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

*CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged* event commit the change when the CheckBox is clicked.

The code in *CellBeginEdit* prevents user from modify a checked CheckBox.

This is an example:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

        With Me.DataGridView1

            .CurrentCell.Value = True

            If .Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "dgvchkOptionA" Then
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dgvchkOptionB").Value = False
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dgvchkOptionC").Value = False
            ElseIf .Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "dgvchkOptionB" Then
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dgvchkOptionA").Value = False
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dgvchkOptionC").Value = False
            ElseIf .Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "dgvchkOptionC" Then
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dgvchkOptionA").Value = False
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("dgvchkOptionB").Value = False
            End If

        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

        If Me.DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
            DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit

        With Me.DataGridView1
            If .CurrentCell Is .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex) And _
                .CurrentCell.Value Then e.Cancel = True
        End With

    End Sub
```